# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar un solo objecto de mi estado?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, funciones

¿cómo están?, tengo este pequeño problema:

Estoy intentando aprender de como usar los **hooks & context**, ya he creeado un **state global** con **context**, pero ahora no sé como actualizar un objecto en concreto.

Mi state global:

```js
"Sources": {
        "defaultSourcesList": {
            "id": 1,
            "value": "hola1"
        },
        "SourcesList": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "value": "hola1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "value": "hola2"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "value": "hola3"
            }
        ]
    },
```

Ahora bien, todo bien con mi **state global**, pero ahora necesito actualizar el valor **"id" que tiene como padre a defaultSourcesList**, mi intento de solución fue esta:

```
 function setSource(e) {
setDefaultHome((prevState) => ({
  ...prevState,
  Sources: {
    defaultSourcesList: {
      id: e,
    },
  },
}));}
```

Ahora bien cuando, ejecuto la función se me actualiza todo el objecto **Sources** y me queda con un valor así:

```
"Sources": {
    "defaultSourcesList": {
        "id": "NuevaID",
        "value": "nuevaValor"
    }, // Lo cual se borra del estado a **SourcesList**
```

Y mis intención es solamente actualizar **"defaultSourcesList"** y no borrar del estado  **"SourcesList"**.

Answer (score 0):

Mi intento de  soluccion numero 2 fue esta:

```js
 function setSource(e) {
    setDefaultHome((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      Sources: {
        defaultSourcesList: {
          id: e,
        },
        SourcesList: prevState.Sources.SourcesList,
      },
```

Tuve que agregar nuevamente a SourcesList mientra tanto, para continuar con el proyecto, pero aun sigo creyendo que debe haber una manera de actualizar defaultSourcesList sin reptir SourcesList que ya se encuentra en el estado